# spring JPA repository not flushing record to database

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I see the response from repository.save() as updated object but same is not getting reflected in database.

I tried using JPArepository also and tried saveandflush method exposed by API but no luck.

Below are the details of code and configuration

Used sql driver with hibernate as middleware.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccmBatch?useSSL=false

spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.datasource.initialize=false

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

POJO :

```
@Entity(name = "jobtracker")
public class JobTracker implements Serializable {
      
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "CCMBATCH")
    String lockVal;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;
    
    public JobTracker() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLockVal() {
        return lockVal;
    }

    public void setLockVal(String lockVal) {
        this.lockVal = lockVal;
    }
    
}
```

Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface JobTrackerRepository extends CrudRepository<JobTracker, Long>{
    
}
```

Caller code :

```
    @Autowired
    JobTrackerRepository repsositoy;
    
    @Transactional
    public boolean acquireJobExecutionLock() {
        LOGGER.info("acquire lock!!!");
        String jobExecutionLockValue = new Date().toString();
        JobTracker tracker = new JobTracker();
        tracker.setLockVal(jobExecutionLockValue);
        JobTracker job = repsositoy.save(tracker);
        LOGGER.info("lock acquired!!!"+job.id+" "+job.lockVal);
        return true;
    }
```

job object used above is printing correct updated values.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>



mysql> desc jobtracker;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CCMBATCH | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: The absence of Transaction-Handling might be the problem. You're not showing all relevant parts of the code.  is there a method annotated @Transactional in the call hierarchy?

Comment: I tried adding @transactional annotation to method in caller code but still no luck

Comment: What do you mean by updated values? You create a new entry each time. Do you want to say that it is not stored in the DB?

Comment: Yes , save() method returns updated value but record not stored in database.

Comment: If `acquireJobExecutionLock` is called from inside the same class, it won't work, too.

Comment: You have show-sql on, do you see the inserts in the log?. That's something that you should show/tell us, too

Comment: I don't see inserts in log and function ```acquireJobExecutionLock``` is called from different workflow not the same class

Comment: Tried adding file data.sql with insert statements for table jobtracker and it worked fine. I can see rows in table.